# Injectivity of $I\leadsto V_I(-)$ and relation to Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The functor $\mathbb A^n_k(-):\mathbf {Alg}_k\to \mathbf{Set}$ is represented by $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k[x_1,\dots ,x_n],-)$; for every ideal $I\subseteq k[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$, there is a subfunctor $V_I(-)\subseteq \ A^n_k(-)$ that sends a $k$-algebra $K$ to the set (in $K^n$) of the solutions of (all the polynomials in) $I$.

Clearly $V_I(-)$ is represented by $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k[x_1,\dots ,x_n]/I,-)$, meaning that the association $I\leadsto V_I(-)$ is injective. However if we restrict the domain of our functors to $\mathbf {Alg}^{\mathbf{red}}_k\subseteq \mathbf {Alg}_k$, i.e. the reduced $k$-algebras, we lose the injectivity: for example, $V_{(x)}(-)$ and $V_{(x^2)}(-)$ become the same functor.

My first question is: if I only consider radical ideals, then the association $I\leadsto V_I(-)$ returns injective? I would say yes because if $I=\sqrt{I}$, then $k[x_1,\dots ,x_n]/I$ is reduced and so $V_I(-)$ is representable also as a functor on $\mathbf{Alg}^{\mathbf{red}}_k$.

My second question is: does Hilbert's Nullstellensatz link in any way with these observations? They remind me of the bijection between radical ideals and algebraic varieties, but I can't see clearly the connection, if it exists. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Doesn't the Nullstellensatz imply that $\sqrt{J}$ is determined literally by $V_J(\overline{k})$? Doesn't this certainly imply what you want? More generally, it's pretty clear that, as you already mentioned, for any $k$-algebra $A$ one has that $\mathrm{Hom}(A,-)$ restricted to reduced schemes is equal to $\mathrm{Hom}(A^\mathrm{red},-)$ and so $A$ and $B$ have the same restrictions iff $A^\mathrm{red}\cong B^\mathrm{red}$. If you think of $\mathrm{Hom}(A/I,-)$ as a subfunctor of $\mathrm{Hom}(A,I)$ then I think one can easily deduce that equality as subfunctors for $I,J$ is equivalent

Comment: to $(A/I)^\mathrm{red}\cong (A/J)^\mathrm{red}$ as $A$-algebras, but these are $A/\sqrt{I}$ and $A/\sqrt{J}$ respectively, so $\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}$. Maybe this is a good time to point out that in my first sentence I should have more clearly said $\sqrt{J}$ is determined by $V_J(\overline{k})$ as a subset of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question:** "My second question is: does Hilbert's Nullstellensatz link in any way with these observations? They remind me of the bijection between radical ideals and algebraic varieties, but I can't see clearly the connection, if it exists. Thanks for any clarification."

**Answer:** It seems your claims follow from the nullstellensatz in the following way: If $k \subseteq K$ is the algebraic closure of a field $k$ and if $I,J \subseteq R:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ let

$$V(I):=\{(a_i)\in K^n: f(a_i)=0\text{ for all $f\in I$}\}.$$

It follows by the HNS that $I(V(J)) = \sqrt{J}$ is the radical of $J$. Hence if $I,J$ are radical ideals with $V(I)=V(J)$ it follows $I=J$. Hence if there is an equality of functors $V_I(-)=V_J(-)$ it follows $V(I)=V(J)$ and hence $I=\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}=J$ and hence the correspondence $I \leadsto V_I(-)$ is injective on ideals.

**Question:** "My first question is: if I only consider radical ideals, then the association $I\leadsto V_I(-)$ returns injective? I would say yes because if $I=\sqrt{I}$, then $k[x_1,\dots ,x_n]/I$ is reduced and so $V_I(-)$ is representable also as a functor on $\mathbf{Alg}^{\mathbf{red}}_k$."

**Answer:** A similar argument proves this claim. If there is an equality of functors $V_I(-)=V_J(-)$, it follows $V_I(K)=V_J(K)$ hence $V(I)=V(J)$ and hence $I=\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}=J$.